# Changing account for Settings Sync in JetBrains community products (IntelliJ IDEA, PyCharm)

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I had 2 JetBrains accounts: one created personally and a long time forgotten, another created for work and actively used. I have been recently setting up IntelliJ IDEA and PyCharm on a new M1 MacBook Pro, and when I was asked to log in for settings sync, I accidentally logged in to the old, unused account. It turned out, that there is no "change account" button in the Settings Sync settings (see screenshots). The only option is to disable settings sync, but there is no log in window when enabling it back.

**What should I do to change the account used for settings sync?**

Screenshot1: IntelliJ IDEA Settings Sync menu sync is enabled:

[image]

Screenshot2: IntelliJ IDEA Settings Sync menu sync is disabled:

[image]

Steps I have tried in different combinations without any success:

- Clear the configuration directory `~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains`
- Reinstall IDEs
- Clear all the [directories used by the IDE to store settings, caches, plugins and logs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519?input_string=changing+account+for+settings+sync+in+jetbrains+community+products+%28intellij+idea%2C)
- Log out from the old account in all browsers
- Log in to the correct account in all browsers
- Delete the old account completely

Incredibly, but even after the old account was deleted, JetBrains products have no issues syncing settings with it. I received several request timeout exceptions at first, which weren't followed by any options to change the Settings Sync configuration. After several sync retries, the request succeeded and no exception has been thrown since. There is nothing.

PyCharm version:

```
PyCharm 2023.2.3 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-232.10072.31, built on October 12, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.8.1+7-b1000.32 aarch64
```

IntelliJ IDEA version:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.3 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-232.10072.27, built on October 11, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.8.1+7-b1000.32 aarch64
```

Log messages when disabling/enabling settings sync

```
INFO - #c.i.s.CloudConfigServerCommunicator - Pushing setting snapshot to the cloud config server...
INFO - #c.i.s.SettingsSyncBridge - Result of pushing settings to the cloud: SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JetBrains Account could be switched in the `Help | Register Plugins...` window in Community Edition:

[image]

Comment: This works, thank you.
This is a very bad UX though.

Comment: Ha! That's so bad, but it worked at least.